# Passing api results in nextjs 14 fetched by server to reduce traffic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

Systeminfo: NEXT.JS 14 Typescript App router

How do I pass api fetch results to the children, to reduce the times the api gets called. Right now I do need to call the api in every page.tsx that I have. (even in some components)

layout.tsx:

```
//imports 

async function fetchConfig() {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.STRAPI_API_TOKEN}`,
    },
    cache: "no-store",
  };

  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.CMS_URL}/api/cmsconfig`, {
      ...options,
      cache: "no-store" as RequestCache,
    });
    const response = await res.json();
    return response;
  } catch (err) {}
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params }: any): Promise<Metadata> {
  const config = await fetchConfig();
  if (!config.data.attributes.AllowSeoIndex) {
    return {
      robots: "noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet, noimageindex, nofollow",
      title: config.data.attributes.BlogTitle,
      description: config.data.attributes.MetaDesc,
    };
  }
  else {
    return {
      title: config.data.attributes.BlogTitle,
      description: config.data.attributes.MetaDesc,
    };
  }
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${rubik.className} bg-shadn3`}>
            <div className="min-h-screen bg-shadn p-4">
              <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto">
                <div className="bg-shadn2 rounded-lg shadow-lg overflow-hidden">
                  <Header />
                  <div className="flex justify-center mt-8">
                    <div className="w-full max-w-screen-lg p-4">{children}</div> <!-- would need the fetch results for example here -->
                  </div>
                  <Footer />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </body/>
    </html>
  );
}
```

header.tsx (component example:)

```
//imports


export async function fetchConfig() {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.STRAPI_API_TOKEN}`,
    },
  };

  try {
    const [configRes] = await Promise.all([
      fetch(`${process.env.CMS_URL}/api/cmsconfig?populate=*`, {
        ...options,
        cache: "no-store" as RequestCache,
      }),
    ]);

    const [configData] = await Promise.all([configRes.json()]);

    return {
      configData,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      configData: null,
    };
  }
}

const Header = async () => {
  const { configData } = await fetchConfig();
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-shadn3"></div>
      <div className="relative bg-opacity-75 bg-dark p-6">
        <div className="flex w-full justify-center">
          <Navbar />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-8 text-center">
          <Image
            className="w-24 h-24 rounded-full mx-auto"
            width={96}
            height={96}
            alt="avatar"
            src={`${process.env.CMS_URL}${configData.data.attributes.BlogAvatar.data.attributes.url}`}
          />
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-100 mt-4">
            {configData.data.attributes.BlogTitle}
          </h1>
          <p className="text-gray-100">
            {configData.data.attributes.BlogDescSecondary}
          </p>
          <p className="text-gray-400 mt-2">
            {configData.data.attributes.BlogDesc}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am fetching on every single page the api again and would like to fetch the data once and pass it to every page and components where I would need them.

If anyone has an idea I would be happy to hear them.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next JS Layout component, pass props to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60457262/next-js-layout-component-pass-props-to-children)